# Return results from multiple models with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have three models — articles, authors and tweets. I'm ultimately needing to use Django REST Framework to construct a feed that aggregates all the objects using the Article and Tweet models into one reverse chronological feed.

Any idea how I'd do that? I get the feeling I need to create a new serializer, but I'm really not sure.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's what I've done thus far.

*app/serializers.py:*

```
class TimelineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.Field()
    title = serializers.CharField()
    author = serializers.RelatedField()
    pub_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

*app/views.py:*

```
class TimelineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that lists all tweet/article objects in rev-chrono.
    """
    queryset = itertools.chain(Tweet.objects.all(), Article.objects.all())
    serializer_class = TimelineSerializer
```

Comment: Is your question about how to merge the two timelines of different objects or how to use DRF to output the already-merged timeline?

Comment: Probably both, on some level ('Fraid I'm a bit of a Django neophyte...). I'll update the code with what I have in a minute, but I've currently created a new view that uses `itertools.chain()` to create a queryset combining `Tweet.objects.all()` and `Article.objects.all()` and gives it to a new serializer that lists the fields common to the two models. Am I anywhere near on the right path?

Comment: You can use this - https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks pretty close to me.  I haven't used ViewSets in DRF personally, but I think if you change your code to this you should get somewhere (sorry - not tested either of these):

```
class TimelineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that lists all tweet/article objects in rev-chrono.
    """
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = list(itertools.chain(Tweet.objects.all(), Article.objects.all()))
        serializer = TimelineSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you're not wedded to using a ViewSet then a `generics.ListAPIView` would be a little simpler:

```
class TimeLineList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TimeLineSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return list(itertools.chain(Tweet.objects.all(), Article.objects.all()))
```

Note you have to convert the output of `chain` to a list for this to work.

Comment: I tried the second route, and am getting the following error: "`base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.model` or `.queryset` attribute." If I replace the "get_queryset" stanza with `queryset = list(itertools.chain(Tweet.objects.all(), Article.objects.all()))`, nothing happens and the whole thing hangs.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Woo, totally got the first variant working. Additional notes for anyone finding this: 1. You need `from rest_framework.response import Response` in `views.py`. 2. When registering the router in `site/urls.py`, I needed to specify `base_name` like so: `router.register(r'timeline', views.TimelineViewSet, 'timeline')`.

Comment: Another note — the fields used in the serializer must be present in both models fed to `itertools.chain()`, merely setting "required=False" for the unique field in the serializer won't do anything.

Comment: you should ideally post the comment as an answer or add the edit to the question so that it helps someone else