# Django REST Framework - Combining and paginating multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am working with Django REST Framework and trying to combine two models, `Tweet` and `Article` into a single list - `Feed`. I want `Feed` to be a list API view that lists `Tweet` and `Article` object chronologically, which I've done so far. This is the code that I have...

```
class FeedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = FeedSerializer
    paginate_by = 10

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        results_list = list(chain(NewsArticle.objects.all(),
                            Tweet.objects.all()))
        sorted_list = sorted(results_list, key=lambda instance: instance.date_added)

        results = list()
        for entry in sorted_list:
            item_type = entry.__class__.__name__.lower()
            if isinstance(entry, Tweet):
                serializer = TweetSerializer(entry)
            if isinstance(entry, Article):
                serializer = ArticleSerializer(entry)
            data_dict = {'item': item_type, 'data': serializer.data}
            results.append(data_dict)

        feed_ser = FeedSerializer(results, many=True)
        return Response(feed_ser.data)
```

This works to the point I can access the data at the API endpoint I set up, however the pagination isn't working with this setup - all items are returned with no options for pagination.

I have followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702300/return-results-from-multiple-models-with-django-rest-framework) but I've tried both methods and I have no luck with pagination on either.

**EDIT:** I know an obvious solution would be to build a base class that they inherit from, and query that table/object, but unfortunately this isn't an option.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you share how you created models ? they are related with foreign key ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for pagination because you are not calling the method *list* from the parent class. That is where the pagination is made, based on your queryset ( look [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)
 at list method in ListModelMixin)

If you want pagination, I see two options:

-- either you implement it yourself, based on the way it is implemented in DRF (link above)

-- or you move all the code that builds your queryset (results) in the *get_queryset* method and let the framework do the pagination.

Good luck.