# django rest framework, serializing multiple models?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose you have a BaseClass and ChildClass1, ChildClass2 with its own fields.

I want to give create a url end point where I can return a list of mixed models with their own fields included.

```
[
 childClass1_obj1,
 childClass2_obj2,
 childClass1_obj3
]
```

I have serializers for each type already setup, and would be good to reuse it somewhere, but if that's not possible, I can live with any solution that works.

[Return results from multiple models with Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702300/return-results-from-multiple-models-with-django-rest-framework) talks about similar stuff, but he only serializes the common part of the two.

Comment: There is an answer here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976202/django-rest-framework-django-polymorphic-modelserialization

Comment: @HairyChris: wow, that one is close.. I tried polymorphic-models, but didn't get it to work (probably due to the fact my models has additional related fields to each other other than parent_link)..  I actually tried overriding `to_native` , but didn't quite get it to work either.

Comment: This is another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048595/django-rest-framework-multitable-model-inheritance-modelserializers-and-nested but the author mentions potential performance problems.