# Filtering results of multiple models under one API Endpoint with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF to generate API for my django app.
I am using the ViewSet class and exposing API endpoints for most of my models at their own path.
I want to allow viewing of my `Endpoint` and `TLSCertificate` models at an `/assets/` path.  As they are both children of an `Organisation` entity, I want to allow the results to be filtered `Organisation`.

So far I have:

*serializers.py*

```
class AssetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    endpoints = EndpointSerializer(many=True)
    certificates = TLSCertificateSerializer(many=True)
```

*views.py*

```
class AssetFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    organisation = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        name='organisation', queryset=Organisation.objects.all())

    project = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        name='project', queryset=Project.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Endpoint
        fields = ['organisation', 'project']

# the object type to be passed into the AssetSerializer
Asset = namedtuple('Asset', ('endpoints', 'certificates'))

class AssetViewSet(CacheResponseAndETAGMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing the Endpoints and Certificates in the Asset list.
    Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978045/serialize-multiple-models-and-send-all-in-one-json-response-django-rest-framewor
    """
    # TODO filtering not functional yet
    filter_class = AssetFilterSet
    filter_fields = ('organisation', 'project',)

    queryset = Endpoint.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        assets = Asset(
            endpoints=Endpoint.objects.all(),
            certificates=TLSCertificate.objects.all(), )
        serializer = AssetSerializer(assets, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This works in returning the objects but does not allow for filtering to take place.
I would appreciate any guidance in how to enable the filtering in this situation?

Comment: at least,you should add `endpoints = self.filter_queryset(Endpoint.objects.all())` to your list function

Comment: Forgive the ignorance, I only partially understand the incomplete code I inherited in the question; can you explain why your comment helps or what it does?  
Adding it just results in exception: 'AssetViewSet' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'