# Combining DRF unrelated models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I cant seem to figure this out. I want to sort by user joined time and user's photo time.

views.py

```
class UserExploreAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    User explore API view.
    """
    serializer_class = TimelineSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = SmallResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        merged_queryset = Places.get_explore_queryset(self.request.user)
        queryset = Places.objects.filter(pk__in=merged_queryset)
        ann_user = User.objects.annotate(photo_time=Extract('date_joined','epoch'))
        return list(chain(ann_user, queryset))
```

serializers.py

```
class SomeUserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeUserModel
        fields = ('photo','id')

class PlacesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, IdFieldMixin):
    photo_link = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    user =  UserRelatedSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'user']
        model = Places

class TimelineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):     
    photo_time = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    places= PlacesSerializer() #this is the error
    someuser= SomeUserModelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['photo_time', 'someuser','places']
        ordering = ('photo_time')
```

When I try to get `places` it says, `User` has no attribute `places`. Well yes. places is a foreignkey to user, user wouldn't have places only the reverse. How do I combine these two models? `SomeUserModel` works because it has `onetoone` with user, but it doesn't work with `places`.

update: added with time

```
class TimelineItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    time = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    places= PlacesSerializer() #this is the error
    someuser= SomeUserModelSerializer()

class TimelineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):     
    time = TimelineItemSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        order_by  = ('time')
```

update

```
json ={
time: 1511654400,
{
   modelA: {'atter1, atter2, atter3}
   modelB: {'atter1, atter2, atter3}
},
time:1511136000, 
{
   modelA: {'atter1, atter2, atter3} # could be empty
   modelB: {'atter1, atter2, atter3}
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What is the end result you have in mind?

Comment: @Anentropic thanks for getting back. Im trying to do as you suggested in the post you had as the answer for the other. I've updated the post, Im guessing you mean the output would be sorted by time first? Im looking to do the same thing, just added with time.

Comment: the first thing you need to do is design a response format that makes sense and is valid JSON