# How to return email verified along with user endpoint?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have implemented DRF and don't want to force email validation, but still use it(remind them on screen). I would like to just return account_emailaddress.verified along with the user endpoint. What is the best way to achieve this? I tried taking hints from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978045/serialize-multiple-models-and-send-all-in-one-json-response-django-rest-framewor), but didn't have success.

The account_emailaddress comes from the django-allauth app I have implemented
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'avatar')
```

View:

```
class UserView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs["user"])
        return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(
            data={
                "message": "User with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["user"])
            },
            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs["user"])
        serializer = UserSerializer()
        user = serializer.update(user, request.data)
        return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(
            data={
                "message": "User with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["user"])
            },
            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )
```

Edit: Thanks to schillingt answer I was able to modify the serializer to work as needed

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress    

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
verified_email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
class Meta:
    model = models.CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'avatar', 'verified_email')

def get_verified_email(self, obj):
    try:
        email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get(user_id=obj.id)
        return email_address.verified
    except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've done it in the past if I just want the field on a different serializer is to use the `SerializerMethod` class. I guessed at the class for `account_emailaddress`.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    verified_email = serializers.SerializerMethod()

    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = (..., 'verified_email')

    def _verified_email(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.account_emailaddress.verified
        except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then on the viewset, you should include `account_emailaddress` in the `select_related` on the `queryset` property so that it doesn't make an additional query per `CustomUser`.

Comment: I get error 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'verified_email'
How can I map it to object allauth.account.models.EmailAddress?

Comment: You need to add 'verified_email' to your CustomUser mode classl: verified_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a source mapping on a serializer field to include fields from a related model, like so (assuming verified is a boolean field);

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    verified = serializers.BooleanField(source='account_emailaddress.verified', read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = models.CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'avatar', 'verified ')
```

Please note that, this also assumes that account_emailaddress is a field on CustomUser model or can be accessed like **custom_user.account_emailaddress** through a OneToOne field.

Comment: It comes from allauth app, editing my question to include this as I forgot
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py

Comment: In this case best method is probably what schillingt mentioned in other answer, adding a SerializerMethodField, finding related account_emailaddress object with a filter there and returning its verified field

Comment: if EmailAddress were related to User model with a OneToOne field instead of a ForeignKey, you could use my solution.