# DRF Serializing multiple models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't serialize multiple object [as this answers says to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978045/serialize-multiple-models-and-send-all-in-one-json-response-django-rest-framewor). In particular it gives me this error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Functional` on serializer `GeneralSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Functional'."

Someone can help me?
My `views.py` is made like this

```
General = namedtuple('General', ('Functional', 'Pfm'))
@csrf_exempt
def listall(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    general = General(
            Functional= SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.values('countexperiments','filetype',rsid=F('snpid__rsid'), FunctionalElement=F('elementid__name'), CellLine=F('celllineid__name')),
            Pfm = SnpsPfm.objects.values('start','strand','type','scoreref','scorealt',rsid=F('snpid__rsid'), pfm_name=F('pfmid__name'))
        )
    serializer = GeneralSerializer(general, many = True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

my `serializers.py`

```
class SnpsFunctionalelementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rsid = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    FunctionalElement = serializers.CharField(max_length=55)
    CellLine = serializers.CharField(max_length=55)

    class Meta:
        model = SnpsFunctionalelement
        fields = ['rsid', 'FunctionalElement', 'CellLine', 'countexperiments', 'filetype']

class SnpsPfmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rsid = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    pfm_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = SnpsPfm
        fields =[ 'rsid','pfm_name','start','strand','type','scoreref','scorealt']

class GeneralSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    Functional = SnpsFunctionalelementSerializer(many=True)
    Pfm = SnpsPfmSerializer(many=True)
```

P.S.: I even tried to work without the DRF serializers doing this

```
all_objects = [SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.values('countexperiments','filetype',rsid=F('snpid__rsid'), FunctionalElement=F('elementid__name'), CellLine=F('celllineid__name')), 
        SnpsPfm.objects.values('start','strand','type','scoreref','scorealt',rsid=F('snpid__rsid'), pfm_name=F('pfmid__name'))]
    ser = serializers.serialize('json',all_objects)
    return JsonResponse(ser)
```

but it gives me this error "`QuerySet` object has no attribute `_meta`"

Comment: Is the error occurring in GeneralSerializer?  ie. do the other two serializers work ok but just not when they are combined?    The error you are getting usually reflects DRF getting unexpected values, eg. object when it expected a queryset or a queryset when it expected a model.

Comment: Yeah the other two serializers work just fine and the queries are the same when they are called alone